# Need help in search on time in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a table like this

```
+----+--------+----------+----------+
| id | time_c | time_r   |  some_id |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 |    900 | 9:00 AM  |        1 |
|  2 |   1000 | 10:00 AM |        2 |
|  3 |   1100 | 11:00 AM |        3 |
|  4 |   1230 | 12:30 PM |        4 |
|  5 |   1300 | 1:00 PM  |        5 |
|  6 |   1410 | 2:10 PM  |        6 |
+----+--------+----------+----------+
```

Now I want to make search on the basis of time. Like if my user is looking for between 12:00 PM and 9:00 AM, it will show him that he ordered 4, 5, 6, 1 or between 9:00 AM to 12:00 PM, it will show 1, 2, 3. And I am using MariaDB/MySQL.

How can i do this? Please help!

Comment: Is this a trick question?  between 12 and 9 is just `WHERE time_c < 900 OR time_c > 1200` and 9 and 12 is `WHERE time_c BETWEEN  900 AND 1200`.  I'm guessing this is homework?

Comment: What are the data types of `time_c` and `time_r`?

Comment: Thanks @Hogan it's working!

Comment: `time_c` is `int` and `time_r` is `varchar` @PaulSpiegel

Comment: hey @Hogan , How can I add `WHERE time_c < 900 OR time_c > 1200` and `WHERE time_c BETWEEN 900 AND 1200` in one line?

Comment: @AbdusSamiul -- it does not makes sense to do that together they are everything and you don't need the filter.

Comment: @Hogan I think it's not about combining the two condtions in one (what, as you wrote, wouldn't make sense), but about one statement that can handle both ranges - one within one day and one over the night. It's difficult for me too, to express the issue in a clear way.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel -- what day it is makes no difference to my tests -- my tests are only looking at time of day.  over the night just does not matter.  Maybe if you give me a specific example how my where won't work.

Comment: @Hogan From 9:00 to 12:00 means `time between 9:00 and 12:00`. From 12:00 to 9:00 means `time between 12:00 and 23:59 or time between 0:00 and 9:00`. The problem is to write one statement, which works for both ranges. That's how i understand it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel -- I understood that -- my query does that.  It does -- really -- it works.

Comment: @Hogan That are two different queries. One for each case.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You got my point. I am also having the same problem!

Comment: @Hogan Your query does work but they are two different queries. I need this in one query.

Comment: I have solved it guys! I just made a condition, 

`if (time_from > time_to) { 
    query = WHERE time_c <= time_to OR time_c >= time_from;
} else if (time_from < time_to) {
    query = WHERE time_c BETWEEN time_from AND time_to;
}` 

thank you guys, and thanks @Hogan for your query!

Comment: @AbdusSamiul -- **NO** `WHERE time_c < 900 OR time_c > 1200` is not two different queries -- it is one where statement that will find time before 9am and after 12 noon.  It will work "overnight" because it does not look at the date.  *It does solve your problem*.  It is simple.  It is what you need.  You should try it.

Comment: I am not saying that `WHERE time_c < 900 OR time_c > 1200` is different queries. That does work overnight but doesn't work on the same day.

Comment: Store only a column of datatype `TIME`, not your time_c and time_r.  You can easily convert as you `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a UNION ALL statement with three different conditions

```
set @time_from = 1200;
set @time_to = 900;

select * 
from some_table
where time_c between @time_from and @time_to

union all

select * 
from some_table
where @time_from > @time_to
  and time_c >= @time_from

union all

select * 
from some_table
where @time_from > @time_to
  and time_c <= @time_to;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/VMVROK94010

**Update**

The solution without UNION using OR conditions is IMHO less readable and is not able to use an index for the WHERE clause:

```
select * 
from some_table
where time_c between @time_from and @time_to
   or @time_from > @time_to
      and (
          time_c <= @time_to
          or
          time_c >= @time_from
      );
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/VFKG60616

Comment: Is it possible to write these three `where` in one line?

Comment: You can write any complex query in one line removing the line breaks :-) But if your point is to have only one select statement without UNION, you can rewrite it to OR conditions. But that might get slower without beeing much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing the time as a varchar, but as a "TIME" format (if you are using MySql). After that, you can sort as "ORDER BY time_r DESC".

Comment: But how can I make the search?

Comment: you can do something like this. 
SELECT * FROM `table` 
where 
    r_time>='09:00:00'and r_time <= '12:00:00';